# How to populate checkbox in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I am using jsp/jstl to render a ui. Now I want to populate a "ui toggle checkbox" checked/unchecked based on a boolean value that I am passing from a controller. How do I do that?
Here is what I have now:

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="enabled" value="${enabled}">
  <label>Is Enabled?</label>
</div>
```

The value of the "${enabled}" is being passed correctly but how to check the box if it is true? Is JQuery/javascript the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this: `${enabled?'checked="checked"':''}`. And put it outside the `value` property.

It uses a ternary operator to check the value of `enabled` and return the corresponding string.